# Best way to populate rows in section in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I'm building an app, where I got several sections in an UITableView. My current solution is collecting my data in a dictionary, and then pick one key for every section. Is there a better solution?

Comment: 1) No of sections = no of keys in dictionary 2) No of rows in section = no of values in dictionary at index(section)

Comment: Exactly, and this is the way to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. Shall I share the code also ?

Comment: Would be great, thanks.

Comment: Use model classes. One model class for sections say SectionModel, inside that create an array which will hold another set of model objects say RowModel. So normally an array will hold set of  SectionModel objects, each SectionModel object will hold an array of RowModel object.

Comment: @Recusiwe, I have added the details in an [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39144215/988169). This will be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example that I wrote. Please note, it error-prone since it is not checking wether the keys exists not does it create a proper cell.

You could do this with a dictionary as well, since you can iterate over its content.

Hope it helps:

```
class AwesomeTable: UITableViewController {

    private var tableContent: [[String]] = [["Section 1, row 1", "Section 1, row 2"], ["Section 2, row 1", "Section 2, row 2"]]

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableContent.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableContent[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let item = tableContent[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a very good practice. 
1). On large scale it is very hard to maintain content of that dictionary.
2). It is almost impossible to do sorting or ordering for big dictionaries.
3). It is very hard to create very complex cells
4). If you have more than 1 or 2 cell types it becomes mess in your cellForRowAtIndexPath
5). Nothing is explicitly set. You only relay on correct content of Dictionary, which is not good.

Comment: I agree, however given the question it answers it. There are many ways of doing this (way)better, one being the answer you gave. In your answer the code is cleaner and easier to read, however I would like to argue that the complexity will still be about the same.

Answer (score 4):

One of the good ways to it - direct model mapping, especially good with swift enums.
For example you have 2 different sections with 3 different type of rows. Your enum and ViewController code will look like:

```
enum TableViewSectionTypes {
    case SectionOne
    case SectionTwo
}

enum TableViewRowTypes {
    case RawTypeOne
    case RawTypeTwo
    case RawTypeThreeWithAssociatedModel(ModelForRowTypeNumberThree)
}

struct ModelForRowTypeNumberThree {
    let paramOne: String
    let paramTwo: UIImage
    let paramThree: String
    let paramFour: NSData
}

struct TableViewSection {
    let type: TableViewSectionTypes
    let raws: [TableViewRowTypes]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    var sections = [TableViewSection]()

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].raws.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let raw = sections[indexPath.section].raws[indexPath.row]
        switch raw {
        case .RawTypeOne:
            // Here return cell of first type
        case .RawTypeTwo:
            // There return cell of second type
        case .RawTypeThreeWithAssociatedModel(let modelForRawTypeThree):
            // And finally here you can use your model and bind it to your cell and return it
        }
    }
}
```

What benefits? Strong typization, explicit modelling, and explicit handling of your various cell types. The only simple thing that you have to do in that scenario it is parse your data into this enums and structs, as well as you do it for your dictionaries.

Comment: That seems to be very promising to solve my issue. However I can't figure out how to parse that data out of my firebase database into the enum. Can I just load the data from my database directly into the enum? Or where do I execute this step?
I already have a struct like the ModelForRowTypeNumberThree in my.
In my app all rowtypes would be the same but populated by 4 different NSDictionarys. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Implement the [table view datasource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) as follows:-

1) Set [number of sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:) = no of keys in dictionary

2) [No of rows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) in section = no of values in dictionary at index(section)